# \only in itemize environment

Tags: beamer, itemize

Basically, latex won't let you put an empty list

```
\begin{frame}
aasdfsafsdaf
\begin{itemize}
   \only<2->{   \item   asdfsdfdsfa } 
   \only<3>{  \item asdfdsafd } 
    
\end{itemize}

dsafsaf
    
\end{frame}
```

It causes problems how do I fix this?

Comment: I really recommend to make yourself familiar with the standards: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228. Otherwise you get a bad reputation :).

Comment: Did the answer solve the problem? If yes, then consider to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
aasdfsafsdaf

\begin{itemize}
\item \uncover<2->{First point.}
\item \uncover<3->{Second point.}
\end{itemize}    

dsafsaf
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]